# MySQL InnoDB table locking on export

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have an `InnoDB` MySQL database. When I export a `SQL` dump, how does the locking occur? Does the entire database lock during the export? Or just the table? Or just the individual rows? How exactly does the export work with `InnoDB`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control what is locked.

To be safest, you can lock all tables like this:

```
mysqldump --lock-all-tables
```

Docs: Lock all tables across all databases. This is achieved by acquiring a global read lock for the duration of the whole dump. This option automatically turns off --single-transaction and --lock-tables.

Or if you're sure you're not going to alter tables:

```
mysqldump --single-transaction
```

Docs: While a --single-transaction dump is in process, to ensure a valid dump file (correct table contents and binary log coordinates), no other connection should use the following statements: ALTER TABLE, CREATE TABLE, DROP TABLE, RENAME TABLE, TRUNCATE TABLE. A consistent read is not isolated from those statements, so use of them on a table to be dumped can cause the SELECT that is performed by mysqldump to retrieve the table contents to obtain incorrect contents or fail.